# Does not implement interface member/does not implement abstract member

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to bind the clover .aar file to xamarin through their android binding library in visual studio. I have gotten it down to two errors:

> 'Decimal' does not implement interface member 'iComparable.ComapreTo(Object)'
>
> 'AuthTask' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])'

Here are the associated files.

```
public partial class Decimal : global::Java.Lang.Number, global::Java.Lang.IComparable {

public partial class AuthTask : global::Android.OS.AsyncTask {
```

I tried adding this to my metadata.xml but nothing changes.

```
 <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.clover.core.internal.calc']/class[@name='Decimal']/implements[@name='Java.Lang.IComparable']" />
```

For the AuthTask I am lost  because I need the implementation and the class AuthTask. I was thinking of just deleting the DoInBackground method but there is no path to this.

UPDATE: 
I was able to add this code to my Metadata.xml

```
<add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.clover.core.internal.calc']/class[@name='Decimal']">
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="CompareTo" native="false" return="int" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
<parameter name="CreatedByDaniel" type="Java.Lang.Object">
</parameter>
</method>
</add-node>

  <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.clover.sdk.util']/class[@name='AuthTask']">
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="DoInBackground" native="false" return="Java.Lang.Object" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
<parameter name="CreatedByDaniel" type="Java.Lang.Object[]">
</parameter>

</method>
</add-node>
```

This took care of the Decimal error however the Auth task error remains. If I change the visibility to protected the Auth error goes away but 160 errors appear saying :

> The name '[method name]' does not exist in the current context

I'm not sure if these classes are needed or not but they seem important. I try to delete them but it's not working.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does your `Decimal` class actually implement `CompareTo(Object)`? Does your `AuthTask` class actually implement `DoInBackground(Object[])`?

Comment: The decimal class does not even need the implementation of IComparable at all. That is why i tried to remove it completely. However the AuthTask does need the AsyncTask, it just hasn't implemented DoInBackground(Object[]). So to answer your question they both don't implement it. @RufusL

Comment: Then doesn't that answer your question? You have two errors which tell you that you have two classes that *say* they implement an interface, yet they don't actually implement all the required methods for the respective interfaces. I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: I am trying to bind this .aar file into C# for xamarin. I can't just edit the C# code, I have to add a line in the metadata.xml to do this. The code I added to this file isn't working. I am asking why it's not working and what I should put there instead. Thanks for responding. @RufusL

Comment: Ok. I don't know about .aar files or xamarin, so I'll leave it to others. But it sounds like you just need to add the required method signatures to the classes, even if the only code in the methods is to throw a `NotImplementedException`

Comment: I updated the code, can you take a look? @RufusL

Comment: @DanielKBoyer are you still using this? I would love to get some more detailed instructions and/or a copy of your Java Bindings Project? I'm trying with the latest .aar and don't really know where to start attacking the errors :/ Thanks!

Comment: So I actually just manually rewrote all of  the code myself into c#. surprisingly that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the update i posted work and the 160 errors need to be edited by adding classes. It only took two more lines to fix everything

UPDATE: I eventually rewrote the Java library into C#. This turned out to be simpler than using the porting library

Comment: Can you share your two more lines pls?